# No suitable constructor found - for Flying

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, count

I have a program that adds animals to a Zoo array. Animals are split between types eg Flying, Terrestrial and Aquatic.

I have a submodule that is adding a flying animal to the array but im getting this error.

No suitable constructor found for Flying(int,double,string)

Here is the main Zoo file that creates the array and is responsible for adding the animals to the array.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Zoo
{
//Private Classfields
private Animals[] animals;
int count;
public final int Maximum_Count = 20;

/********************************************************************
*Default Constructor:
*Import: None
*Export: Address of new Zoo Object
*Assertion: Creates a Default Zoo Object for count and animals array.
********************************************************************/

public Zoo()
{
    count = 0;
    animals = new Animals[Maximum_Count];
}

/*****************************************************************
*Alternate Constructor:
*Import: inCount(Integer), inAnimals(Animals[])
*Export: Address of New Zoo Object
*Assertion: Creates alternate object if valid and fails otherwise.
*****************************************************************/

public Zoo(int inCount, Animals[] inAnimals)
{
    if(validateCount(inCount))
    {
        animals = new Animals[Maximum_Count];                   //Probably Wont have to validate Count
        for(int ii = 0; ii < Maximum_Count; ii++)
        {
            inAnimals[ii] = new Animals(inAnimals[ii]);
        }
    }
}

/*********************************************************************************
*Copy Constructor:
*Import: inZoo(Zoo)
*Export: Address of New Zoo Object
*Assertion: Creates a new Zoo Object with an identical object state as the import.
*********************************************************************************/

public Zoo(Zoo inZoo)
{
    count = inZoo.getCount();
    animals = inZoo.getAnimals();
}

//Mutators

/*********************************
*Submodule: setCount
*Import: inCount(Integer)
*Export: None
*Assertion: Sets count to inCount.
*********************************/

public void setCount(int inCount)
{
    if(validateCount(inCount))
    {
        count = inCount;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Count");
    }
}  

/*************************************
*Submodule: setAnimals
*Import: inAnimals(Animals[])
*Export: None
*Assertion: Sets animals to inAnimals.
*************************************/

public void setAnimals(Animals[] inAnimals)
{
    if(inAnimals == null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Animals can not be found, array is empty.");
    }
    else
    {
        animals = new Animals[inAnimals.length];
        for(int ii = 0; ii < inAnimals.length; ii++)
            {
                animals[ii] = new Animals(inAnimals[ii]);
            }
    }
}

public int getCount()
{
    return count;
}

public Animals[] getAnimals()
{
    Animals[] animalsCopy;
    animalsCopy = new Animals[animals.length];
    for(int ii = 0; ii < animals.length; ii++)
    {
         animalsCopy[ii] = new Animals(animals[ii]);
    }
    return animalsCopy;
}

/****************************************************************************
*Submodule: equals
*Import: inObject(Object)
*Export: same(boolean)
*Assertion: Checks if two Zoo objects are equal according to array and count.
****************************************************************************/

public boolean equals(Object inObject)
{
    Zoo inZoo;
    boolean same = false;
    if(inObject instanceof Zoo)
    {
        inZoo = (Zoo)inObject;
        if(count == inZoo.getCount())
        {
            if(sameAs(animals,inZoo.getAnimals()))
            {
                same = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return same;
}

public String toString()
{
    String outString = "Count: " + count;
    for(int ii = 0; ii < animals.length; ii++)
    {
         outString = outString + ("Animals" + ii + ": " + animals[ii].toString());
    }
    return outString;
}

/**************************************************
*Submodule: addFlying
*Import: None
*Export: None
*Assertion: Adds a Flying Animal to the Zoo(Array).
**************************************************/

public void addFlying()
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String species;
    int numWings;
    double mass;
    System.out.println("Please enter the Species of the Flying Animal.");
    species = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the Mass of the Flying Animal.");
    mass = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter the Number of Wings the Flying Animal has.");
    numWings = sc.nextInt();
    Flying temp = new Flying(numWings,mass,species);
    animals[count] = temp;
    count++;
}

/*******************************************************
*Submodule: addTerrestrial
*Import: None
*Export: None
*Assertion: Adds a Terrestrial Animal to the Zoo(Array).
*******************************************************/

public void addTerrestrial()
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String species;
    int numLegs;
    double mass;
    System.out.println("Please enter the Species of the Terrestrial Animal.");
    species = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the Mass of the Terrestrial Animal.");
    mass = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter the Number of Legs that the Terrestrial Animal has.");
    numLegs = sc.nextInt();
    Terrestrial temp = new Terrestrial(species,numLegs,mass);
    animals[count] = temp;
    count++;
}

/****************************************************
*Submodule: addAquatic
*Import: None
*Export: None
*Assertion: Adds an Aquatic Animal to the Zoo(Array). 
****************************************************/

public void addAquatic()
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String species;
    int numFins;
    double mass;
    System.out.println("Please enter the Species of the Aquatic Animal.");
    species = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the Mass of the Aquatic Animal.");
    mass = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter the Number of Fins that the Aquatic Animal has.");
    numFins = sc.nextInt();
    Aquatic temp = new Aquatic(species,numFins,mass);
    animals[count] = temp;
    count++;
}

/*********************************************************************************
*Submodule: displayAnimals
*Import: None
*Export: None
*Assertion: Converts Flying,Terrestrial and Aquatic to a String and Prints it out.
*********************************************************************************/

public void displayAnimals()
{
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        if(animals[i] instanceof Flying)
        {
            Flying test1 = new Flying((Flying)animals[i]);
            System.out.println(test1.toString());
        }
        if(animals[i] instanceof Terrestrial)
        {
            Terrestrial test2 = new Terrestrial((Terrestrial)animals[i]);
            System.out.println(test2.toString());
        }
        if(animals[i] instanceof Aquatic)
        {
            Aquatic test3 = new Aquatic((Aquatic)animals[i]);
            System.out.println(test3.toString());
        }
    }
}

//Private Submodules

/*************************************************
*Submodule: sameAs
*Import: array1(Object[]), array2(Object[])
*Export: sameAs
*Assertion: Checks if the two arrays are the same.
*************************************************/

private boolean sameAs(Object[] array1, Object[] array2)
{
    boolean sameAs = true;
    if(array1.length != array2.length)
    {
        sameAs = false;
    }
    else
    {
        int count = 0;
        do
        {
            sameAs = array1[count].equals(array2[count]);
            count++;
        }
        while(sameAs && (count < array1.length));
    }
    return sameAs;
}

/***********************************************************************
*Submodule: validateCount
*Import: inCount(Integer)
*Export: valid(boolean)
*Assertion: inCount must be greater than 0 and less than or equal to 20.
***********************************************************************/

private boolean validateCount(int inCount)
{
    return((inCount > 0) && (inCount <= 20));
}
}
```

Here is the Flying file that it says cannot find suitable constructor.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Flying extends Animals
{
//Class Constants.
public static final String type = "Flying";

//Private Classfields
private int numWings;

/*****************************************
*Default Constructor:
*Import: None
*Export: Address of new Flying Object
*Assertion: Creates default Flying Object.
*****************************************/

public Flying()
{
    super();
    int numWings = 0;
}

/**************************************************************************
*Alternate Constructor:
*Import: inMass(Real), inSpecies(String), inNumWings(Integer)
*Export: Address of new Flying Object
*Assertion: Creates the alternate constructor if valid and fails otherwise.
**************************************************************************/

public Flying(String inSpecies, double inMass, int inNumWings)
{
    super(inSpecies, inMass);
    if(validateWings(inNumWings))
    {
        numWings = inNumWings;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Number of Wings");
    }
}

/**************************************************************************
*Copy Constructor:
*Import: inFlying(Flying)
*Export: Address of new Flying Object
*Assertion: Creates an object with an identical object state as the import.
**************************************************************************/

public Flying(Flying inFlying)
{
    super(inFlying);
    numWings = inFlying.getNumWings();
}

//Mutators

/************************************************************************
*Submodule: setNumWings
*Import: inNumWings(Integer)
*Export: None
*Assertion: Sets the numWings to inNumWings if valid and fails otherwise.
************************************************************************/

public void setNumWings(int inNumWings)
{
    if(validateNumWings(inNumWings))
    {
        numWings = inNumWings;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Number of Wings");
    }
}

//Accessors

public int getNumWings()
{
    return numWings;
}

/******************************************************************************
*Submodule: equals
*Import: inObject(Object)
*Export: same
*Assertion: Two flying objects are equal if they have the same number of wings.
******************************************************************************/

public boolean equals(Object inObject)
{
    boolean same = false;
    if(inObject instanceof Flying)
    {
        Flying inFlying = (Flying)inObject;
        if(numWings == inFlying.getNumWings())
        {
            same = true;
        }
    }
    return same;
}

public String toString()
{
    return(type + super.toString() + "Num Wings is: " + numWings);
}

//Private Submodules

/***********************************************************************
*Submodule: validateNumWings
*Import: inNumWings(Integer)
*Export: valid(boolean)
*Assertion: Number of Wings must be even to be valid and greater than 0.
***********************************************************************/

private boolean validateNumWings(int inNumWings)
{
    return((inNumWings % 2 == 0) && (inNumWings > 0));
}
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

The constructor's parameters need to be in the same order

so you have defined it as

```
public Flying(String inSpecies, double inMass, int inNumWings)
```

so its needs to be called as

```
Flying temp = new Flying(species, mass, numWings);
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters in the constructor are in the wrong order.

The error message clearly states "*Flying(int,double,string) cons not found*"

Which means you have not defined a constructor that accepts "int, double, string" as the parameter